# React-native: how to get JSON from backend and put the objects in react-native elements, such as Text?

Tags: json, react-native, fetch

I am trying to fetch JSON data from a php file, which seems to work fine; I can alert values from the JSON. But I want to be able to put these values on the mobile app screen in Text elements or whatever. And I want this to happen when the screen opens, not when a button is pressed. So I made a function that fetches the JSON and I'm trying to return a value in Text elements. This function is called from the rendering. I don't get error messages, but it isn't working. Nothing shows up.

Here is the code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, AsyncStorage, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { UsersMap } from '../UsersMap';
import { PrimaryButton } from '../Buttons';
import styles from './styles';

class RestOptions extends Component {

    getSearchResults() {
        fetch('http://192.168.1.3/Restaurant_App/php/search_results.php')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            var JSON_Test = responseJson["distance"][0];
            //Alert.alert(JSON_Test);
            return (
                <View>
                    <Text>{JSON_Test}</Text>
                </View>
            );
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }

    setReservation = () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('SetReservation');
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <UsersMap />
                {this.getSearchResults()}
                <PrimaryButton
                    label="Set Reservation"
                    onPress={() => this.setReservation()}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
};

export default RestOptions;
```

This is what happens. The JSON value should appear between the map and the button:

[Search Results Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TunTU.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in order to fetch the data as the screen opens, you should use the lifecycle method `componentWillMount`, which executes before the first render, and then store the result in the component's state. [React docs on state and lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

```
class RestOptions extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            jsonTest: null
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.getSearchResults();
    }

    getSearchResults() {
        fetch('http://192.168.1.3/Restaurant_App/php/search_results.php')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            var JSON_Test = responseJson["distance"][0];
            //Alert.alert(JSON_Test);
            this.setState({ jsonTest: JSON_Test });
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }
//...
```

Then you can display the value on the `render()` method:

```
render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <UsersMap />

            <Text>{this.state.jsonTest}</Text>

            <PrimaryButton
                label="Set Reservation"
                onPress={() => this.setReservation()}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

If the response is an array of values, you can use `map()` to display each of them in their own `Text` element:

```
{this.state.jsonTest.map((value, index) => <Text key={index}>{value}</Text>)}
```